# Pass expressions to function to evaluate within data.table to allow for internal optimisation

Tags: r, data.table

**Preread**

I went through some material here on SO:

- [Evaluating function arguments to pass to data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969289/evaluating-function-arguments-to-pass-to-data-table)
- [evaluate expression in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59000463/evaluate-expression-in-data-table)
- [Access data.table columns with strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562602/access-data-table-columns-with-strings)

and after getting a perfect answer to my [previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62006630/use-string-representation-of-variable-in-i-for-data-table), I am trying to once and for all get my head around how to canonically deal with `data.tables` in functions.

**Underlying Problem**

What I eventually want is to create a function which takes some `R` expressions as inputs and evaluates them in the context of a `data.table` (both in the `i` as well as in the `j` part). The quoted answers tell me that I have to use some `get/eval/substitute` combination if my inputs become more complicated than just a single column (in which case I could live with the `..string` or the `with = FALSE` approach [1]).

My real data is rather big, so I am concerned about computational time.

Ultimately, if I want to have full flexibility (that is passing in expressions rather than bare column names), I understood that I have to go for an `eval` approach:

Codes speaks a thousand words, so let's illustrate what I found out so far:

*Setup*

```r
library(data.table)
iris <- copy(iris)
setDT(iris)
```

*Workhorse Function*

```r
my_fun <- function(my_i, my_j, option_sel = 1, my_data = iris, by = NULL) {
   switch(option_sel,
      {
         ## option 1 - base R deparse
         my_data[eval(parse(text = deparse(substitute(my_i)))), 
                 eval(parse(text = deparse(substitute(my_j)))),
                 by]
      },
      {
         ## option 2 - base R even shorter
         my_data[eval(substitute(my_i)), 
                 eval(substitute(my_j)),
                 by]

      },
      {
         ## option 3 - rlang
         my_data[rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::enexpr(my_i)),
                 rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::enexpr(my_j), data = .SD),
                 by]

      },
      {
         ## option 4 - if passing only simple column name strings
         ## we can use `with` (in j only)
         my_data[,
                 my_j, with = FALSE,
                 by]

      },
      {
         ## option 5 - if passing only simple column name strings 
         ## we can use ..syntax (in 'j' only)
         my_data[,
                 ..my_j]
                 # , by] ## would give a strange error

      },
      {
         ## option 6 - if passing only simple column name strings
         ## we can use `get`
         my_data[,
                 setNames(.(get(my_j)), my_j),
                 by]

      }
   )
}
```

*Results*

```r
## added the unnecessary NULL to enforce same format
## did not want to make complicated ifs for by in the func 
## but by is needed for meaningful benchmarks later
expected <- iris[Species == "setosa", sum(Sepal.Length), NULL]
sapply(1:3, function(i) 
               isTRUE(all.equal(expected,
                                my_fun(Species == "setosa", sum(Sepal.Length), i))))
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE

expected <- iris[, .(Sepal.Length), NULL]
sapply(4:6, function(i)
               isTRUE(all.equal(expected,
                                my_fun(my_j = "Sepal.Length", option_sel = i))))
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

**Questions**

All of the options work but while creating this (admittedly not so) minimal example I had a couple of questions:

1. To profit the most from `data.table`, I have to use code which the internal optimizer can profile and, well, optimize [2]. So which of the options 1-3 (4-6 are only here for completeness and lack full flexibility) works "best" with `data.table`, that is which of these can be internally optimized to take full benefit from `data.table`? My quick benchmarks showed that the `rlang` option seems to be the fastest.
2. I realized that for option 3 I have to provide `.SD` as data argument in the `j` part, but not in the `i` part. This is due to scoping that much is clear. But why does `tidy_eval` "see" the column names in `i` but not in `j`?
3. Any other solution which can be even optimized further?
4. Using by with option 5 results in a strange error. Why?

**Benchmarks**

```r
library(dplyr)
size     <- c(1e6, 1e7, 1e8)
grp_prop <- c(1e-6, 1e-4)

make_bench_dat <- function(size, grp_prop) {
   data.table(x = seq_len(size),
              g = sample(ceiling(size * grp_prop), size, grp_prop < 1))
}

res <- bench::press(
   size = size,
   grp_prop = grp_prop,
   {
      bench_dat <- make_bench_dat(size, grp_prop)
      bench::mark(
         deparse    = my_fun(TRUE, max(x), 1, bench_dat, by = "g"),
         substitute = my_fun(TRUE, max(x), 2, bench_dat, by = "g"),
         rlang      = my_fun(TRUE, max(x), 3, bench_dat, by = "g"), 
         relative = TRUE)
   }
)

summary(res) %>% select(expression, size, grp_prop, min, median)
# # A tibble: 18 x 5
#    expression      size grp_prop      min   median
#    <bch:expr>     <dbl>    <dbl> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>
#  1 deparse      1000000 0.000001  22.73ms  24.36ms
#  2 substitute   1000000 0.000001  22.56ms   25.3ms
#  3 rlang        1000000 0.000001   8.09ms   9.05ms
#  4 deparse     10000000 0.000001 274.24ms 308.72ms
#  5 substitute  10000000 0.000001 276.73ms 276.99ms
#  6 rlang       10000000 0.000001 114.52ms 119.21ms
#  7 deparse    100000000 0.000001    3.79s    3.79s
#  8 substitute 100000000 0.000001    3.92s    3.92s
#  9 rlang      100000000 0.000001    3.12s    3.12s
# 10 deparse      1000000 0.0001    29.57ms  36.25ms
# 11 substitute   1000000 0.0001    37.22ms  41.56ms
# 12 rlang        1000000 0.0001     19.3ms  24.07ms
# 13 deparse     10000000 0.0001   386.13ms 396.84ms
# 14 substitute  10000000 0.0001   330.22ms 332.42ms
# 15 rlang       10000000 0.0001   270.54ms 274.35ms
# 16 deparse    100000000 0.0001      4.51s    4.51s
# 17 substitute 100000000 0.0001       4.1s     4.1s
# 18 rlang      100000000 0.0001      2.87s    2.87s
```

---

[1] `with = FALSE`or `..columnName` does however work only in the `j` part.

[2] I learned that the hard way when I got a significant performance boost when I replaced `purrr::map` by `base::lapply`.

Comment: option 4 is invalid, this is not how `with=F` is meant to be used.

Comment: hmm,despite the fact that it works, I would be curious to learn what the intended use is then? I thought `x <- "Species"; iris[, x, with = FALSE]`is the intended use? (of course this is now superseded by `iris[, ..x]`)

Comment: Yes, exactly, or providing integer. It is meant to provide data.frame-like interface, by removing `with()`-like interface that data.table provides. Which was the initial motivation to write and release package back in 2006.

Comment: So your 1. comment should be read as "option 4 is outdated, `with=F`  should nowadays be replaced by the `..x` syntax"? Don't want to be nitpicking, but I was confused by the term "invalid", as apparently it is valid but outdated code. Or do I miss agains something?

Comment: Option is not outdated, but it should be used with integer or character, and not with expression, for expression this option will be ignored. BTW. check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLrdYhizEMg

Comment: Ok, but if you kook into my example that's exactly what I have done - used it with a character. Hence my confusion. But good that we are now on the same page, thanks for your explanation!

Comment: Sorry then, if you pass characters and not expressions then the whole substitution is redundant

Comment: Understood and that's what I wrote: `"(4-6 are only here for completeness and lack full flexibility)"` and in the code`"## option 4 - if passing only simple column name strings we can use "with" (in j only)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need for fancy tools, just use base R metaprogramming features.

```r
my_fun2 = function(my_i, my_j, by, my_data) {
  dtq = substitute(
    my_data[.i, .j, .by],
    list(.i=substitute(my_i), .j=substitute(my_j), .by=substitute(by))
  )
  print(dtq)
  eval(dtq)
}

my_fun2(Species == "setosa", sum(Sepal.Length), my_data=as.data.table(iris))
my_fun2(my_j = "Sepal.Length", my_data=as.data.table(iris))
```

This way you can be sure that data.table will use all possible optimizations as when typing `[` call by hand.

---

Note that in data.table we are planning to make substitution easier, see solution proposed in PR
[Rdatatable/data.table#4304](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4304).

Then using extra `env` var substitute will be handled internally for you

```r
my_fun3 = function(my_i, my_j, by, my_data) {
  my_data[.i, .j, .by, env=list(.i=substitute(my_i), .j=substitute(my_j), .by=substitute(by)), verbose=TRUE]
}
my_fun3(Species == "setosa", sum(Sepal.Length), my_data=as.data.table(iris))
#Argument 'j'  after substitute: sum(Sepal.Length)
#Argument 'i'  after substitute: Species == "setosa"
#...
my_fun3(my_j = "Sepal.Length", my_data=as.data.table(iris))
#Argument 'j'  after substitute: Sepal.Length
#...
```

Comment: A classic. Didn't see the wood for the trees. I'll quickly run some benchmarks on that :) But looks so straight forward that I am ashamed that I did not come with that solution myself :)